# KitchenAid Pro mixer clicking noise

Tags: equipment

I have a KitchenAid pro mixer that is making a slow clicking noise. It gets faster as I turn up the speed. I first noticed it after replacing a stripped worm follower gear. It sounds like it's coming from the motor. I have checked/cleaned/and re-greased all the other gears several times, and I am confident they are all working properly. Everything looks fine. As far as I can tell. It is not a huge clicking noise, but almost sounds like the fan is hitting something as it goes around. Is this something I should worry about? If I should worry about it, how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you reinstall the motor-brushes in the correct orientation? Brushes tend to wear asymmetrically, and can produce a clicking sound if you get them in wrong.

Comment: Is it cyclical with the movement of the paddle/whisk?  Is it possible that you need to adjust the position of rotating element over the bowl?

Comment: I've done the same thing. I changed the worm gear and the worm follower gear and now I hear a clicking sound and I know that its all in place properly.

Comment: Mine is brand new, out of the box and, it clicks without no load and no mixer attachment, model 550

Answer (score 3):

Does it only do it under higher load? Mine clicks a little bit when kneading dough, and I determined that it was actually the bowl moving a bit. I have a lift-bowl model, but it could be either that or the hinge on a tilt model.

If it is under load, try pushing on the bowl to eliminate movement. If it happens even when empty, this isn't it.

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me after replacement of lower gear housing.
It's caused from having the two motor mount screws too tight.  I realized that could cause a bit of stress on the harmonics of the motor operation.  Loosened and reinstalled just barely over a light snug, that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

After I changed the nylon gear, I missed a small piece of the striped nylon gear that was hiding in all the grease. After running it for a few seconds it started clicking. I tore it down and spun the gear with a punch until i found a spot that would catch, and found 2 VERY small pieces of the stripped nylon gear in the teeth of large planetary? gear. After removal it's running like new. If it happens again i will change the grease, and find the piece in the gear. Very small, hard to see pieces in the back of the gear teeth.